# simple application: gauss bonnet and geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I have two (supposedly simple) problems that are solvable by the local Gauss-Bonnet Theorem. Any help is extremely appreciated!

> Let $D$ be a compact surface in $\mathbb R^3$ homeomorphic to a disk, with a piecewise smooth boundary. Then Gaussian curvature satisfies $$ \int_D K \, dA + \int_{\partial D} \kappa_g \, ds + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 2 \pi, $$ where $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature wrt. to the interior of $D$, $\alpha_i$ are the outer angles at the corners in $\partial D$ and $n$ is the number of these corners.

***i)*** Let $F$ be surface in $\mathbb R^3$ that is homeomorphic to a disk, and let $\int_F K \, dA \leq \pi $. Show that geodesics don't intersect. (Hint: use the above stated theorem)

***ii)*** Let $M$ be a compact oriented surface in $\mathbb R^3$, and let $K > 0 $. Show that simple closed geodesics don't intersect. (Hint: use the above stated theorem)

$\,$

***edit.*** i know now, what the above questions should look like:

***i)*** Let $F$ be surface in $\mathbb R^3$ that is homeomorphic to a disk, and let $\int_F K \, dA \leq \pi $. Show that geodesics don't intersect *twice*.

***ii)*** Let $M$ be a compact oriented surface in $\mathbb R^3$, and let $K > 0 $. Show that simple closed geodesics *do* intersect.

Comment: Part ii seems false: the unit sphere is compact and oriented with $K = 1$, and any great circle is a simple closed geodesic, but any two great circles intersect. Perhaps I'm missing something, though.

Comment: Part i seems false, too: take the unit disk in the plane. Its total curvature is 0. But any two diameters intersect, and all straight lines in the disk are geodesic.

Comment: that explains why it was so hard to solve... thanks!

Comment: You also might want to run away form the person who suggested these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part ii) might be false, do Carmo writes:

If the two geodesics didn't meet, then they would be the boundary of a region $R$ with Euler characteristics $\chi(R)=0$. Hence by Gauss Bonnet we have $\int K dA = 0$ and that's a contradiction since $K>0$.